# Efficient ways of assigning value based on conditional in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

The objective is to assign a value to the column `EXPECTED T`. The value to be assigned is `C1 S +  C2 B`  if there is `EM` in column `C2 B`, else the value is image of the value at `C2 B`.

To realise the  objective, the following code is propose

```
data = {'C1 S': ['AB','AB','CD','CD','CD'],
        'C2 B': ['EM','EM','EM','F','F'],
        'EXPECTED_OUTPUT': ['AB EM','EB EM', 'CD EM','F','F']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['EXPECTED T']=df['C1 S']+' '+ df['C2 B']
mask = df ['C2 B'].str.contains ( r'EM', na=True )
df.loc [~mask, 'EXPECTED T'] = df.loc [~mask, 'C2 B']
```

But, I wonder if there is more Pythonic of achieving similar result then the above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) or [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), also is possible use here [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
mask = df['C2 B'].str.contains ( r'EM', na=True )
df['EXPECTED T'] = np.where(mask, df['C1 S']+' '+ df['C2 B'], df['C2 B'])
```

---

```
#alternative
df['EXPECTED T'] = np.where(mask, df['C1 S'].str.cat( df['C2 B'], sep=' '), df['C2 B'])
print (df)
  C1 S C2 B EXPECTED_OUTPUT EXPECTED T
0   AB   EM           AB EM      AB EM
1   AB   EM           EB EM      AB EM
2   CD   EM           CD EM      CD EM
3   CD    F               F          F
4   CD    F               F          F
```

Or:

```
mask = df['C2 B'].str.contains ( r'EM', na=True )
df['EXPECTED T'] = df['C2 B'].mask(mask, df['C1 S']+' '+ df['C2 B'])
```